# How can I run Android camera application from adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

How can I run android camera program from adb shell?
I know that I should use am but I do not know what command should I exactly enter

I used this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.camera
```

But it didn't work!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Alternatively, you can start the camera in 2 other ways

1. Image capture mode: `adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"`
2. Video capture mode: `adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE"`

**Other information**

1. To focus: `adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS"`
2. To take a photo or start/stop recording: `adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA"`

**Other notes**

f the keycode string e.g KEYCODE_CAMERA, does not work, lookup the constant value from the API description. Example: [KEYCODE_CAMERA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_CAMERA)

```
KEYCODE_CAMERA: Added in API level 1
Constant Value: 27 (0x0000001b)
```

Comment: At least on my Android, input keyevent takes an int. `input keyevent 27` is the camera button.

Comment: Noted. If the string value does not work, you have to look it up from the API description. I have added notes to that effect on the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried it on LG L7 running 4.0.4, and it yielded "error: device not found"

Comment: Whether this works if the device is connected in remote machine and the Jenkins run in another machine

Comment: You can do it without double quotes

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add to Keo Malope's answer that while [IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) and [VIDEO_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) are likely to work on most devices, I have encountered cases where they don't work as expected. In this case, we have two more constants that we can try:

- [STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA)

  - `adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`
- [VIDEO_CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA)

  - `adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA`

Comment: Great stuff. For my vanilla Lenovo P2, STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA worked great as it pulled up the non-stock camera properly, whereas the IMAGE_CAPTURE option in the answer pulled up some strange camera I've never seen (which took photos but didn't save them to disk).

Answer (score 2):

- Create a `CameraActivity` class.
- Implement camera functionality there and add to `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
- Then use following command:

  ```
  am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n [package-name].CameraActivity
  ```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify exact component name (name of activity).

> am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.camera/.CameraEntry

It is working on my device (HTC Desire HD), but I can't guarantee that it'll work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me here

```
adb shell am start -n com.mediatek.camera/com.android.camera.CameraActivity
```