# Launching an app through adb

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I am new to Android. I am trying to launch the camera app thru adb. Can some one help me on this.
Here is my apk:

```
package:/system/app/Camera.apk=com.android.camera
```

I am using this cmd  in my `adb: am start -n com.android.camera/.Camera`

It gives me the error:
Starting: `Intent { cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera }`

```
Error type 3
```

Error:

```
Activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.camera.Camera} does not ex
ist.
```

Can some one help

Comment: You are using Mono for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.camera/.CameraEntry`
```

From: [How can I run android camera application from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402158/how-can-i-run-android-camera-application-from-adb-shell)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So if I want to open the other apps I should use the Entry.

Comment: No probs, feel free to mark it as the answer if it works for you ;)