# Android command-line photo

Tags: android, photo

I have a nexus4 with a broken touchscreen. Controlling the bootloader with power and volume keys still works, so I put rootbox on it. Now I can login to the root prompt using adt. As I want to use it as timelapse camera, I wonder how is it possible to take a photo and save it to a specific folder using the command line? 
Then I could set up a cron job and download images using adt.

Comment: Perhaps better suited on [android.SE]

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this: [How can I run Android camera application from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402158/how-can-i-run-android-camera-application-from-adb-shell)

In short:

> 1. Image capture mode: adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"
> 2. Video capture mode: adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE"
> 3. To focus: adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS"
> 4. To take a photo or start/stop recording: adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA"

Comment: My camera takes picture by tap instead of KEYCODE_CAMERA: `adb shell "input tap x y"`, use a point instead of x y for example `input tap 100 100`.

Comment: by default, it opens back camera. How about selfi?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable USB debugging using this [link](https://%20https://itoolab.com/unlock-android/enable-usb-debugging-from-pc/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20the%20Settings,turn%20the%20toggle%20to%20Off) (from Shell).

Then reboot it and once the device started try below, (mentioned in previous answer)

Image capture mode: `adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"`

Video capture mode: `adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE"`

To focus: `adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS"`

To take a photo or start/stop recording: `adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA"`